# iframe in Android webpage

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Digital India App</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome to Digital India</h1>
    <img src="digi4.jpg" width="368" height="168" align="middle">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p align="justify">The Digital India programme is a flagship programme of the Government of India with a vision to transform India into a digitally empowered society and knowledge economy.</p>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">
          <li><a href="#page2">Atal Pension Yojana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Pradhan Mantri Awas Yojana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Pradhan Mantri Jeevan Jyoti Bima Yojana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page5">Pradhan Mantri Surakhsha Bima Yojana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page6">Online Aadhaar Application</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="#page7">Pradhan Mantri Kaushal Vikas Yojana (PMKVY)</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="#page8">Sukanya Samriddhi Yojana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page9">Beti Bacaho Beti Padhao Scheme</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page10">Pradhan Mantri Jan-Dhan Yojana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page11">Online PAN Card Application</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page12">Online Voter ID Application</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page13">About</a></li>
            </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">Atal Pension Yojana</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

      <div align="justify"><img src="atal.png" width="330" height="152" border="2" align="absmiddle">

     <p> <strong>The Atal Pension Scheme will bring security to ageing Indians while at the same time promote a culture of savings and investment among the lower and lower middle class sections of society. One of the greatest benefits of the scheme may be enjoyed by the poorer sections of society. The government of India has decided to contribute 50 percent of the user’s contribution or INR 1,000 a year (whichever is lower) for a period of five years. 
      This contribution will, however, be enjoyed only by those who are not income tax payers and those who join the scheme before 31 December 2015. </strong></div>
      <!--<p align="center"><a href="https://www.npscra.nsdl.co.in/scheme-details.php"> Atal Pension Yojana</a></p>-->

    <iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.npscra.nsdl.co.in/scheme-details.php" height="500" width="500">

</iframe>
<p>



    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>



<div data-role="page" id="page3" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">Pradhan Mantri Awas Yojana</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
    <p align="justify">
    <img src="housing.jpg" width="330" height="152" border="2" align="absmiddle">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><strong>The Pradhan Mantri Awas Yojana, the government of India will undertake to construct about two crore houses by the year 2022. Each house provided under the scheme will involve a central grant of about INR 1 lakh which may go up to INR 2.3 lakhs.This will come as part of a 6.5 percent interest rate subsidy scheme (previous schemes had an interest rate subsidy of about 1 percent). This means that the applicants from lower income groups who avail of the housing scheme may apply for a housing loan with interest subsidy of 6.5 percent. The tenure or term for these housing loans may go up to 15 years and the total benefit received by such loan subsidy will add up to INR 1 to 2.3 lakh each. Currently housing loan interest rates are estimated at about 10.5 percent.</strong></p> 

   <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://mhupa.gov.in/pmay/index.htm" height="500" width="500">

</iframe>



   <!-- <p align="center"><a href="http://mhupa.gov.in/pmay/index.htm">Pradhan Mantri Awas Yojana</a>   -->
  </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">Pradhan Mantri Jeevan Jyoti Bima Yojana</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
      <img src="jjb.png" width="330" height="112" border="2" align="middle">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p><strong>Pradhan Mantri Jeevan Jyoti Bima Yojana will be made available to anyone between the age group of 18 to 50 years. The concerned person should also have a bank account. People, who avail this policy before they are 50 years old, will be allowed to enjoy the risk of life cover till the age of 55 years. However, they will need to pay the premium on a consistent basis in order to be provided that benefit.</strong></p>


     <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.sbilife.co.in/sbilife/content/10_8843" height="500" width="500">

</iframe>


    <!--  <p align="center"> <a href="http://www.sbilife.co.in/sbilife/content/10_8843">State Bank Of India, Pradham Mantri Jeevan Jyoti Bima Yojana</a></p>-->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page5" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">Pradhan Mantri Surakhsha Bima Yojana</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <img src="sub.png" width="330" height="112" border="2" align="middle">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p align="justify"><strong>The scheme will be a one year cover, renewable from year to year, Accident Insurance Scheme offering accidental death and disability cover for death or disability on account of an accident. The scheme would be offered / administered through Public Sector General Insurance Companies (PSGICs) and other General Insurance companies willing to offer the product on similar terms with necessary approvals and tie up with Banks for this purpose.
        All savings bank account holders in the age 18 to 70 years in participating banks will be entitled to join. In case of multiple saving bank accounts held by an individual in one or different banks, the person would be eligible to join the scheme through one savings bank account only. Aadhar would be the primary KYC for the bank account.</strong></p>

     <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://pmjdy.gov.in/JanSuraksha/Default.aspx" height="500" width="500">
 </iframe> 



     <!-- <p align="center"><a href="http://pmjdy.gov.in/JanSuraksha/Default.aspx">Pradhan Mantri Surakhsha Bima Yojana</a></p>-->
  </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page6" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">Online Aadhaar Application</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
      <img src="aadhaar.jpg" width="330" height="152" border="2" align="middle">        
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p align="justify"><strong>Aadhaar is a 12 digit individual identification number issued by the Unique Identification Authority of India on behalf of the Government of India.
        This number will serve as a proof of identity and address, anywhere in India. Aadhaar letter received via India Post and e-Aadhaar downloaded from UIDAI website are equally valid. Any individual, irrespective of age and gender, who is a resident in India and satisfies the verification process laid down by the UIDAI can enrol for Aadhaar.
        Each individual needs to enroll only once which is free of cost.
        Each Aadhaar number will be unique to an individual and will remain valid for life. Aadhaar number will help you provide access to services like banking, mobile phone connections and other Govt and Non-Govt services in due course.</strong></p>
      <p align="justify">&nbsp;</p>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.uidai.gov.in" height="500" width="500">
 </iframe> 

<!-- <div align="center"><a href="http://appointments.uidai.gov.in">Online Aadhaar Application</a>
        </p>-->


    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<!--<div data-role="page" id="page7">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Online Aadhaar Application</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
-->

<div data-role="page" id="page8" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">Sukanya Samriddhi Yojana</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   

      <p align="justify"><img src="suk.jpg" width="330" height="197" border="2" align="absmiddle">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p align="justify"><strong>Save for every girl child in India. Reinforcing this idea, Prime Minister Narendra Modi launched ‘Sukanya Samriddhi Account Scheme’, a small savings scheme as a part of the ‘Beti Bachao Beti Padhao’ campaign. It is also considered a part of the government’s initiative to increase the percentage of domestic savings, which has reduced from 38% of the GDP in 2008 to 30% in 2013. This scheme will encourage parents to save for the education and future of their girl child.   </strong></p>

   <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/investments/sukanya-samriddhi-yojana-account/index.page" height="500" width="500">
 </iframe>    




     <!-- <p align="center"><a href="https://www.sbi.co.in/portal/web/govt-banking/sukanya-samriddhi-yojana">State Bank Of India, Sukanya Samriddhi Yojana</a></p>-->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page9" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">Beti Bacaho Beti Padhao Scheme</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
      <p align="justify"><img src="bb.jpg" width="196" height="188" border="2" align="absmiddle">
      <p align="justify"><strong>The scheme aims at making girls independent both socially as also financially through education. This approach of the Government can facilitate in generating awareness and improving the efficiency of delivery of welfare services meant for the women. In this scheme, the Ministry of Women and Child Development is functioning in collaboration with various other Ministries like Education Ministry and Health Ministry.    </strong></p>

      <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://wcd.nic.in/BBBPscheme/launch/workshop/main.htm" height="500" width="500">
 </iframe>  




      <!--<p align="justify">&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p align="center"><a href="http://wcd.nic.in/BBBPscheme/launch/workshop/main.htm">Beti Bacaho Beti Padhao Scheme</a></p>-->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page10" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center"> Pradhan Mantri Jan-Dhan Yojana</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <div align="justify"><img src="jd.gif" width="330" height="152" border="2" align="middle">

      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p><strong>Pradhan Mantri Jan-Dhan Yojana (PMJDY) is National Mission for Financial Inclusion to ensure access to financial services, namely, Banking/ Savings & Deposit Accounts, Remittance, Credit, Insurance, Pension in an affordable manner. 

        Account can be opened in any bank branch or Business Correspondent (Bank Mitr) outlet. PMJDY accounts are being opened with Zero balance. However, if the account-holder wishes to get cheque book, he/she will have to fulfill minimum balance criteria.</strong></p>
    </div>

    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.pmjdy.gov.in/scheme_detail.aspx" height="500" width="500">
 </iframe>  


   <!-- <p align="center">
    <a href="http://www.pmjdy.gov.in/scheme_detail.aspx">Pradhan Mantri Jan-Dhan Yojana</a></p>-->      
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page11" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Online PAN Card Application</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p align="justify"><img src="pan.jpg" width="330" height="165" border="2" align="middle">
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
      <p align="justify"><strong>PAN, or permanent account number, is a unique 10-digit alphanumeric identity,in the form of a laminated card, allotted to each taxpayer by the Income Tax Department.
        •PAN enables the department to link all financial transactions, such as tax payments, TDS or TCS credits, returns of income/wealth/gift/FBT, specified transactions, correspondence, etc, of the person with the Income Tax department. </strong></p>
      <p align="justify"><strong>The primary objective of PAN is to use a universal identification key to track financial transactions  to prevent tax evasion. It also serves as an identity proof(Proof of Identity),a  document for opening a new bank account, a new landline telephone connection or a mobile phone SIM card. It is PERMANENT for your life and will not change with change of your address or marital status.
        One can have only one PAN.  A penalty of Rs. 10,000  is liable to be imposed under section 272B of the Income-tax Act, 1961 for having more than one PAN. If a person has been allotted more than one PAN then he should immediately surrender the additional PAN card(s).
        It needs to be surrendered after death of the person. </strong></p>

      <p>&nbsp;</p>

      <iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.tin-nsdl.com/pan/pan-index.php" height="500" width="500">
 </iframe>  




     <!-- <p align="center"> <a href="https://www.tin-nsdl.com/pan/pan-index.php">Online New PAN Card Application</a></p>-->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page12" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">Online Voter ID Application</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

      <p align="justify"><img src="vot.jpg" width="188" height="218" border="2" align="middle">

      <p align="justify"> <strong>The voter ID card or EPIC is an identification card issued by the Election Commission to all eligible voters (Indian citizens who are above 18 years of age) to enable voter identification on Election Day. All those who are already enrolled in the voter's list are eligible to receive a voter ID card. These cards carry personal details and a distinct identification number. (In future, data of a biometric nature like digital signature and fingerprints may also be contained inside a microchip, embedded in the given card.) The EPIC proves to be a unique identity document for all Indians. 
        It is helpful not only for casting a vote in elections but also acts as an identity proof and address proof for opening a bank account, getting a new gas connection, and online reservations for travel and accommodation.</strong></p>
      <p align="justify"><strong>In fact nowadays almost all government agencies, insurance companies, mortgage companies like bank agencies (if you are going to apply for mortgage or any other personal loan), and claim firms (Insurance claims) ask for a voter id number. A voter ID card is also essential for registration in the electoral roll in case a person migrates to a place other than the place of his/her domicile.</strong></p>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://eci-citizenservices.nic.in/" height="500" width="500">
 </iframe>  




     <!-- <p align="center"> <a href="http://www.nvsp.in/forms/form6.html">Apply for new Voter ID</a></p>-->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
    </div>
</div>



<div data-role="page" id="page13" data-add-back-btn="true">
<div data-role="header">
        <h1 align="center">About Digital India</h1>
    </div>
<div data-role="content">   
    <p>Digital India is a great initiative and a flagship programme by the Government of India to digitally empower society and knowledge economy.</p>
    <p>In this application I have brought most of the Digital India progammes in one place so that any one can accsess these wonderful projects at their convience from their Android mobile phones. There is one link to State Bank of India and the other is ICICI Bank only, (most banks provide the services) as there will be too many links. Clicking each link at the bootom of the page will take you to its respective site</p>
    <p>&nbsp; </p>
     <p>An internet connection is assumed.</p>
    <p>Logos courtesy Government of India.</p> 
    <h5>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015.</h5>
  <div data-role="footer">
  <h4>&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4> 



    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Used iframe to load external webpage in Android webpage. This works. But it is not very elegant. The external webpage loads automatically how do I make the user click a link button to do the same ? Wondering if there was any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In you markup, instead of setting the iframe src, save the url in a data-attribute, e.g.:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" data-srcurl="https://www.npscra.nsdl.co.in/scheme-details.php" src="" height="500" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Then use the pagebeforeshow and pagebeforehide events to set the src prop of the IFRAME:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#page2", function(){ 
    var $iframe = $("#page2 #myIframe");
    $iframe.attr("src", $iframe.data("srcurl")); //with later jQuery use .prop()
});
$(document).on("pagebeforehide","#page2", function(){ 
    $("#page2 #myIframe").attr("src", "");  //with later jQuery use .prop()
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bywdzbLx/)**

Comment: This content can’t be shown in a frame

There is supposed to be some content here, but the publisher doesn’t allow it to be displayed in a frame. This is to help protect the security of any information you might enter into this site.

Try this
•Open this in a new window

Comment: @RanjanMitra, if it is not your content, and they don't like to be hosted in other people's sites, then opening a new window/tab is probably the best solution.

Comment: Now another problem connection to the server was unsuccessful though I have added loadUrlTimeoutValue 30000. Frustrating....